# Try changing singular noun to plural by using structure and function in c programming

Tags: c

Write a program based on the following requirements:

(i) Define a structure named Noun which holds a string called singular and another string
named plural.

(ii) Write a function named pluralize that will convert a singular noun to plural form and store it into the string plural in the structure variable. The function should receive a structure as output argument and return nothing.
The rules to transform a singular noun to plural form are shown below:

‘y’ Replace it with ‘ies’

‘s’ , ‘ch’, ‘sh’, ‘x’ Add ‘es’

Others Add ‘s’

(iii) Write another function named addNouns that will open a binary file, nouns.dat, for appending, and add some nouns into it. The function should receive the structure variable (as defined in (i) above) as input argument and return 1 (true) to indicate that the data has been added successfully, or return 0 (false) otherwise. [Note: Do not append if the noun is found on the binary file.]

(iv) Your program should allow a continuous request for a singular noun for conversion until no more nouns are available.

Q7*. Write a program to read data from nouns.dat (created in Q6). Write the data from nouns.dat into
a text file, nouns.txt, and also display it on screen in the format as shown below:
Church Churches
Toolbox Toolboxes
Table Tables
Copy Copies

i'm using MS Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9.4
it keeps giving me error like syntax error! But i cannot find what os wrong with my code. The program is able to write the data to the binary file, but when i read these data into the structure variable, it give me unknown character...

```
int addNouns(Noun *s);
void pluralize(Noun *noun);
typedef struct{
    char singular[30], plural[30];

}Noun;

void pluralize(Noun *noun)
{
    int len;
    FILE *f2;
    f2 = fopen("nouns.dat", "rb");
    if (f2 == NULL)
    {
      printf("Unable to open file!\n");
      exit(-1);
    }
    while (fread(&noun->singular, sizeof(noun->singular), 1, f2) != 0) {
        len = strlen(noun->singular);
        if (noun->singular[len - 1] == 'y')
        {
             noun->singular[len - 1] = 'i';
             noun->singular[len] = 'e';
             noun->singular[len + 1] = 's';
             *noun->plural = noun->singular;
        }
else if (noun->singular[len - 1] == 's' || noun->singular[len - 1] == 'ch' ||
noun->singular[len - 1] == 'sh' || noun->singular[len - 1] == 'x')
        {
            noun->singular[len - 1] = 'e';
            noun->singular[len] = 's';
            *noun->plural = noun->singular;
        }
        else {
            noun->singular[len - 1] = 's';
            *noun->plural = noun->singular;
        }
    }

}
int addNouns(Noun *s)
{

    char yon;
    FILE *f1;
    f1 = fopen("nouns.dat", "ab");
    printf("Do you want to enter nouns>");
    scanf("%c", &yon);
    while (toupper(yon) == 'Y') {
        printf("Enter a nouns(singular)>");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", &s->singular);
        fwrite(&s->singular, sizeof(s->singular), 1, f1);
        printf("Do you want to enter nouns>");
        scanf(" %c", &yon);

    }
    if (fwrite(&s->singular, sizeof(s->singular), 1, f1)==1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;

    fclose(f1);
}

void main()
{
    Noun noun;
    addNouns(&noun);
    pluralize(&noun);
    printf("Singular\t\tPlural\n");
    printf("%s\t\t%s", noun.singular, noun.plural);

    system("pause");
}
```

Hope can outcome the output like below:
Church  Churches
Toolbox Toolboxes
Table   Tables
Copy    Copies

Comment: At least point out the compiler errors.

Comment: Gooses, mouses, mooses, foots, tooths, mans, womans // leafs, elfs, wolfs, hoofs, halfs // childs

Answer (score 0):

**Several things are wrong** with this code.

First of all in line:

`noun->singular[len - 1] == 'sh' || noun->singular[len - 1] == 'x')`

**' ' denote chars 'sh' is not a character it is a string so must be denoted by "sh"**

**You cannot compare strings with chars**

Typedef Noun at the very beginning otherwise the **function prototypes won't know what you are referring to**

```
typedef struct{
    char singular[30], plural[30];

}Noun;
int addNouns(Noun *s);
void pluralize(Noun *noun);
```

You can't copy strings like this.
    *noun->plural = noun->singular;

**Use strncpy()** to copy strings from src to dest.

The **implementation is not optimal**

Why are you using the current struct instead of a word/suffix combination? 
Also, there are possibilities of buffer overflows all over the place.
Allocate memory on the heap. Don't forget to free them.

```
typedef struct{
    char *word, *suffix;
}Noun;
```

Hope this serves as a guideline where you are going wrong.

Comment: "Typedef Noun at the very beginning otherwise the function prototypes won't know what you are referring to", this is helping me!!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: in typedef structure, word/suffix, school teacher did not teach lol

Comment: *noun->plural = noun->singular;
changed to this
strcpy(*noun->plural, noun->singular);

Comment: Exception thrown at 0x0FA4E559 (ucrtbased.dll) in Practical 10.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xFFFFFFCC. occurred
The compiler give me this error...